# Get 2 plots and a vertical legend next to each other

Tags: r, plot

I want to have two plots next to each other and a common legend for both.

Like This:

Plot 1 | Plot 2 | Legend

Unfortunately, the legend is plotted inside of the second plot...

This is my current approach:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
  plot(...)
  plot.new()
  plot(...)
  legend("center", ...)
```

I thought with par(mfrow=c(1,3)) I would get one row with 3 columns of plots - so exactely the result I wanted to obtain.
Is the legend maybe not treated as a plot but as belonging to plot number 2 and so it is plotted with the same column?

Comment: its best if you can make your question reproducible so people can help you a little easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. `legend` needs a `plot.new` in front of it, if you want to have it as a "standalone" plot.

```
par(mfrow=c(1, 3))
plot(1:10)
plot(1:10)
plot.new()
legend("center", pch=1, legend=c("x", "y"))
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you as an example. Nevertheless, there are better libraries to be used such as `ggplot2` or `plotly`.

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2), oma = c(0, 0, 0, 2))
plot(hp~mpg, data=mtcars, col=cyl,pch=19)
plot(disp~wt, data=mtcars, col=cyl,pch=19)
legend(x=6, y=250, legend=as.numeric(levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))), pch=19, col= as.numeric(levels(factor(mtcars$cyl))) )
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I still got the problem of the legend being plotted within the second plot - might be cause by the package I'm using for the plots and legends.
I'm doin gan analysis with the imsig package which comes with functions for plotting networks.

When I'm inserting the step with the par() into the function plot_network of the imsig package, the legend is still plotted within the second plot :/

Comment: Then, you can move it specifying `x` and `y` in `legend()`